# How to pull out multiple IDs with one select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say the table has IDs (1,2,3,4,5). I want to pull out 1,4,5 with one select statement. How can I do it?

```
Select m.Member_ID,m.Member_Name,r.Title from Member m,Record r
where m.Member_ID=r.Member_ID
and m.Member_ID=79
```

I want to pull out multiple IDs instead of only 79.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
Select m.Member_ID,m.Member_Name,r.Title from Member m,Record r
where m.Member_ID=r.Member_ID
and m.Member_ID IN(1,4,5)
```

although you can individually list then in your WHERE clause as well. Just make sure you wrap them in parenthesis to ensure proper operator presedence.

```
Select m.Member_ID,m.Member_Name,r.Title from Member m,Record r
where m.Member_ID=r.Member_ID
and (m.Member_ID=1 OR m.Member_ID=4  OR m.Member_ID=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `in` statement.  But also, you should learn proper, explicit `join` syntax:

```
Select m.Member_ID, m.Member_Name, r.Title
from Member m join
     Record r
     on m.Member_ID = r.Member_ID
where m.Member_ID in (1, 4, 5);
```